# Handler execute slower then preset delayed

Tags: android, handler, timing

I have the following code in onCreate of one of my activity. I want to execute some codes after a delay . After searching on stackoverflow i tried the recommended method using Handler Class.

However , I noticed from the logcat that the postdelayed excutes later than 1000ms most of the time . Did i make a mistake ? Thanks.

```
    Log.e("Test","Test On");

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.e("Test","Test Off");
        }
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: how did you measure the delay?

Comment: hi , i did not resume the delay i execute this every time in my activity onCreate.

Comment: i mean how do you know that Runnable is called too late?

Comment: hi , i check through the timing of the logcat output.

Comment: this explains everything, use System.currentTimeMillis() twice and Log.d() the difference

Comment: Hi , i have done the above and the delay is still more than 1000ms . It ranges from 1000ms to 4000ms .

Comment: most liklely you are doing some heavy computarions after calling postDelayed